# May Shnayim Mikrah be done little by little each day?

Tags: mishnah-berurah, shnayim-mikra

I know of many people who do Shanyim Mikrah every day (ex. one aliyah per day.) Halachipedia states the practice [has been common](https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Shnayim_Mikra_V%27Echad_Targum#cite_ref-37) to do such, and sources it [here](https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Shnayim_Mikra_V%27Echad_Targum#cite_note-37).

However, later down in thes same page, it states that:

> "If it's possible it's good not to interrupt when reading Shnayim Mikrah and a pious person should be strict about this. [35] Some allowed interrupting to answer a question."

It then brings down the source from the MB:

> "[Mishna Brurah 285:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.285.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes if it's possible it's good not to interrupt when reading Shnayim Mikrah and a pious person should be strict about this. [Kaf Hachaim 285:15](https://www.sefaria.org/Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.285.15.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) quotes this in the name of the Mekubalim and adds that if one is very thirsty one may interrupt to drink with a bracha before and after. Kaf HaChaim Palagi 27:4 writes that in middle of Shnayim Mikrah one may not interrupt to talk even in Hebrew."

My question is regarding what this MB (and other sources in the above quote) says in relation to the first point: does it mean that one may not talk during the reading of it, even if it is just one aliyah, ***or does it mean that one should do it beginning to end, without interruption?*** (I *have* heard that one should do it all at once.)

I am looking four sources on how to understand the MB here: does he allow one to read it part by part, or does his ruling that one should not interrupt imply he believes one should read it start to finish at once?

Comment: It seems you are only asking if it should be done in one sitting, not if it may be done little by little each day which it clearly can.

Comment: see elya rabba, which seems to mean that one should not be mafsik with a different matter (rather than an idea of talking), but that one should complete it all at once. https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.285.1?lang=he&with=Eliyah%20Rabbah&lang2=he